# c# How to query Datatable by LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I know how to query data table by LINQ but broker names coming in the columns of data table for which i am not able to query it. see how data is coming. screen shot attached.

[image]

see **BofA Merrill Lynch or Deutsche Bank** these are broker name which is coming as a column.

This way i generally query data table by LINQ.

```
                ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("EarningID") == earningsid
                    && x.Field<string>("EarningsType") == earningsType
                    && x.Field<string>("EarningsType") == earningsType
                    && x.Field<string>("DisplayInCSM") == DisplayInCSM
                    && x.Field<string>("Type") == Type
                    && x.Field<string>("Broker") == BrokerCode
                    && x.Field<string>("Period") == Period
                    );
```

Now tell me how could i add one more clause in where condition that broker name.

How could i mention column name in where clause like `&& x.Field<string>("Deutsche Bank")` as a result LINQ query should return value say **19738.5877**

in my above linq query i mention few condition in where but how could i mention **Deutsche Bank** column name in where and i should get value **19738.5877**

please share the right LINQ query where i can also mention column name in where with other condition. thanks

### EDIT

I tried this way to query column but getting error **Additional information: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.**

```
private string GetData<T>(DataTable table, DataTable dt, int earningsid, string earningsType, string DisplayInCSM,
    string Type, string BrokerCode, string Period, T value) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    string brokername = GetBrokerName(dt, BrokerCode);

    IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
            .Where(r => r.Field<int>("EarningID") == earningsid
                && r.Field<string>("EarningsType") == earningsType
                && r.Field<string>("DisplayInCSM") == DisplayInCSM
                && r.Field<string>("Type") == Type
                && r.Field<string>("Broker") == BrokerCode
                && r.Field<string>("Period") == Period
                && r.Field<T>(brokername).CompareTo(value) >= 0);

    string rowValue =(rows.FirstOrDefault()[brokername]==DBNull.Value ? "" : rows.FirstOrDefault()[brokername].ToString());

    return rowValue;
}
```

EDIT 1

```
------
            IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                    .Where(r => r.Field<int>("EarningID") == earningsid
                        && r.Field<string>("EarningsType") == earningsType
                        && r.Field<string>("DisplayInCSM") == DisplayInCSM
                        && r.Field<string>("Type") == Type
                        && r.Field<string>("Broker") == BrokerCode
                        && r.Field<string>("Period") == Period
                        /*&& r.Field<T>(brokername).CompareTo(value) >= 0*/
                        && r.Field<object>(brokername) != DBNull.Value);
```

for above code i am getting this error
**Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.**

Comment: see how i am querying data table. i need to mention also broker name in same where clause which is coming as pivot data.

Comment: `EF.Property<string>(x, "Deutsche Bank")` ?

Comment: Is this question about how to use columns that have spaces in their names?

Comment: i am not using EF. i have a data in data table and that data i want to query by LINQ

Comment: see the output. there are few columns are fixed/static but broker name coming as pivot order. so i need to query that data where i will mention broker name with other condition in where.

Comment: Try : x.Field<string>("Deutsche Bank") != DBNull.Value

Comment: i want a single value which appear before broker name.

Comment: @jdweng i see your code and implement but getting error `Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare an `int` with `System.DbNull`, that's what the exception tells you. The only `int` in your parameters is `earningsid` and indeed your screenshot shows null values for that column.

Good that the [`Field` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-5.0) also supports nullable types (`r.Field<int?>("...")`):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
    .Where(r => r.Field<int?>("EarningID") == earningsid
        && so on ...
```

Comment: Change From : <int?> To : <object>

Comment: @jdweng: well, that would not even compile since you cannot compare an object with an `int` with the `==`-operator. It doesn't make much sense anyway because you want to compare the `int` in the table with the `int`-parameter, so why converting it to something else? The `Field`-method suppports nullable types, so we should use this feature :)